# different ways of accessing a share

Tags: linux, mount, smb

Could anyone explain to me the difference between using

```
mount -t cifs 192.168.1.10/Folder /mnt/folder

mount 192.168.1.10:/volume1/Folder /mnt/folder

smb://192.168.1.10/Folder
```

to access a share? Does the way how a share is mounted also affect permission levels?

Comment: well, `-t cifs` is required for older systems, but I'm not sure why you have to go through `\Volume1` to get to `\folder` if folder is shared. as for permissions, yes and no. if you are using a disk level share (like c$) the permissions on the share do narrow the filesystem permissions, so you may end up with less privledge, but you should never end up with more privilege than your user has on the disk location.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying or omitting the `-t cifs` should not make a difference as `mount` will autodetect the CIFS format anyway. Neither option should affect the permissions.

The last line you specify isn't a command in an of itself, do you mean if you were to specify that option in a GUI File Browser?

Comment: The title was a bit missleading as you mentioned the last line does not really mount a share.

Is there actually a difference between mounting a share and accessing it over a file browser using the last line?

I was wondering why :/volume1/ can be omitted in the first line. Does that mean that mount 192.168.1.10/Folder /mnt/folder would also work?